# Delete from table where table field does not match another table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables, one named "stations" and another named "records." "stations" is related to the records listed in "records" by **stations.id=records.stationID**.

Many of my "stations" are not related to any data which appears in the "records" table, and I would like to delete the rows of "stations" in which their corresponding id does not match any value in records.stationID.

I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM stations
WHERE stations.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT records.stationID
                          FROM records);
```

which worked in principle, but I let it run for 8 hours overnight and it hadn't completed in the morning. I think this is because it requires the subquery to be executed for each record in "stations," which contains 9000+ rows. (is that correct?)

How can I expedite the deletion process? I've tried various inner joins as well, i.e.:

```
DELETE FROM stations
INNER JOIN records on stations.id=records.stationID
WHERE stations.id not in records.stationID;
```

which gives me a syntax error. I also tried the following, which don't appear to do anything, really:

```
DELETE stations.*
FROM stations
INNER JOIN records ON records.stationID=stations.id
WHERE stations.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT records.stationID
                          FROM records);
```

and

```
DELETE FROM stations
INNER JOIN records on records.stationID=stations.id
WHERE stations.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT records.stationID from records);
```

Any ideas?

**SOLVED:** I just needed to add an index to the "records" table. Thanks to all for the help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using, MySQL or Microsoft SQL Servre? Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Try a `left join` and delete where `records.stationID is null`

Comment: This first think you tried should have worked. 9,000 records is nothing to a database. This should took a few seconds max.

Comment: @DanGuzman using MySQL, sorry about that.

Comment: @Chuck should also have mentioned that the "records" table has 107 million rows. Each distinct stationID in "records" corresponds to ~10,000 rows. I think that's why it's taking so long

Comment: That could be. Try anyone of the queries, and in a second window, do a select count, and see if the total records is going down. It might take a long time, but at least you would know that it is actually doing something.

Comment: @WEI_DBA unfortunately left join method does the same thing as the first query in my OP. I ran that statement about 15 minutes ago, just aborted it, and saw that 15 stations were deleted from the table. So, it works, but again is just incredibly slow. The count(*) of the stations table after finishing the right delete statement should be 993 (from 9000+ originally)

Comment: Stupid question time... Are both tables indexed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
DELETE stations FROM stations
LEFT JOIN records on stations.id=records.stationID
WHERE records.stationID IS NULL;
```

Also check do you set index for `records.stationID`.

Comment: I tried this, gave me a syntax error. "DELETE stations.* FROM stations..." worked, though it was just as slow as the first query statement I listed in my OP.

Comment: Sorry, try now. Query takes a long maybe because one of tables haven't index - `stations.id` or `records.stationID`.

Comment: Yeah the records.stationID isn't indexed. I'll add one now. How would I change the delete statement to reflect the index, or will MySQL automatically use the index to trim the processing time?

Comment: Mysql will automatically use it

Answer (score -1):

Try a  **LEFT OUTER JOIN :**

```
SELECT * FROM stations
LEFT OUTER JOIN records
ON stations.stationID= records.stationID
WHERE records.stationID IS null
```

Comment: @Chuck this is a sub query which is give you records for deletion